# Nginx isn't serving static rails asset files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

My nginx.conf file is using the recommended config from the rails guides:

```
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.org;
    root /home/ec2-user/sites/mysite/production/current/public;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;

      add_header ETag "";
      break;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend-mysite;
    }
  }
```

Problem is requests for css and js compiled files like this:

```
http://mysite.org/assets/application-0230217054b1f5b5f386a270a526ceca.css
```

are returning 403 status.

I've taken a look and I can see the asset files are there in public/assets/

What is wrong with my nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I wasn't looking at the nginx error log before for some reason.  Once I looked there I could see that those assets were getting  "permission denied" error for them.  I tracked down this problem and had to make sure every directory from the root to the location of the asset files had:

```
chmod +x
```

on it.